# How to move application out of the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I deployed an app on Google App Engine, how can I move it out off the Google App Engine, and host all the stuff in my own domain? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) is an open source platform that mimics the Google AppEnginge functionality, you can install it on your own server and run your app in it.

Comment: If you're using Python, don't forget TyphoonAE (http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/).